# How do I create files in the server from within a browser deployed JavaFx 2.0 Application

Tags: javafx-2

I need to create files in my local server from within a JavaFx 2.0 application, the code is in good shape but when I deploy the app and try to remotely activate the create file button, the file is not created. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Java Console` (Control Panel - Java - Advanced - Show Console) and check exceptions.

Most probably it would be security exception as giving application in browser permissions to access file system is very dangerous.

To resolve that you'll have to sign application before deploying.